I have converted my react ts app to react vite ts app. The app works well in development but the build is not working
I have converted my react ts app to react vite ts app. The app works well in development but the build is not working. I have followed the steps to convert react app to vite react app. The app is wworking well in development but when i create a production build , the build is getting created but when i serve the build i got a white screen and error message in console
I have tried some suggestion from vite and other links but not able to resolve this issue
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import fs from 'fs';
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'
export default defineConfig({
// depending on your application, base can also be "/"
base: '',
plugins: [
react(),
viteTsconfigPaths(),
VitePWA({
injectRegister:"auto",
registerType:"prompt",
strategies:"generateSW",
includeAssets: ['favicon.ico', 'apple-touch-icon.png'],
workbox:{
globPatterns:['**/*.{js,css,ico,png,svg,jpg,jpeg,webp,woff,woff2,webmanifest}'],
},
manifest:{
name:"OneJam",
short_name:"OneJam",
description:"One digital workspace to provide your buyers with everything they need to make their decision and your sellers with everything they need to win the deal.",
theme_color:"#000000",
icons:[
{
src:"/favicons/196x196.png",
sizes:"196x196",
type:"image/png",
},
{
src:"/favicons/512x512.png",
sizes:"512x512",
type:"image/png",
},
],
},
})
],
server: {
// this ensures that the browser opens upon server start
open: true,
// https: {
//     key: fs.readFileSync('./.cert/localhost.key'),
//     cert: fs.readFileSync('./.cert/localhost.crt'),
// },
// this sets a default port to 3000
port: 3000,
},
})
Above is my vite config file
